# VBA loop counter not adding non-whole numbers

Tags: vba, loops, integer, decimal, counter

I'm have a piece of code I'm running a loop with to add up the number of PPC hours that show up based on a matched date criteria. The hours I am trying to add are 0.2 increments. When the loop runs it looks like its rounding 0.2 down to 0 and the total comes out to 0. When I run it with the hours changed to 1 it adds them up correctly. Is there a way to have a loop counter add non-whole numbers such as 0.2?

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim i As Integer 'for counters
Dim Assy, Solder, QC, Weld, Test, PPC As Long 'variables to hold std hours total

Assy = 0
Solder = 0
QC = 0
Weld = 0
Test = 0
PPC = 0

'Cycle through all tabs to find myrange and count work hours by type
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set StartCell = Range("I12")
        For i = 12 To 123
            If Range("I" & i).Value = 44154 Then
                If Range("I" & 1) = "Assy" Then
                    Assy = Assy + Range("I7").Value
                ElseIf Range("I" & 1) = "Solder" Then
                    Solder = Solder + Range("I7").Value
                ElseIf Range("I" & 1) = "Weld" Then
                    Weld = Weld + Range("I7").Value
                ElseIf Range("I" & 1) = "Test" Then
                    Test = Test + Range("I7").Value
                ElseIf Range("I" & 1) = "PPC" Then
                    PPC = PPC + Range("I7").Value
                ElseIf Range("I" & 1) = "QC" Then
                    QC = QC + Range("I7").Value
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B2") = PPC
```

Comment: Use a double and not integers, longs, and variants?

Comment: I tried doing that but it still yielded 0. It's almost like it's in the counter, when I hover over PPC in the code while running it, it only shows up as a single digit i.e. 0, 1, 5, etc...it doesn't add up i.e 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, etc...

Comment: Because it is a long... It only stores integers (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2...) you need to use the proper type which is a double.

Comment: Is it right that you are always adding I7? You could probably dispense with the loop.

Comment: in this example, yes. Once I get this figured out I need to loop it through multiple columns so it will move over to I8, I9, I10, etc...

Comment: @Warcupine I see what you're saying now...so change Dim Assy, Solder, QC, Weld, Test, PPC As Long to As Double?

Comment: Yes and also the ```Assy, Solder, QC, Weld, Test``` are currently variants you need to repeat the double after each one. variants can store doubles but they should be properly typed.

Comment: @Warcupine I'm not sure I followed that last part...How do I do that? Sorry, still learning the ropes here :)

Comment: ```Assy as Double, Solder as Double``` and so on.

Comment: Ah gotcha! That seems to have worked! Sweet, thank you so much!